# How I can change currency on wordpress checkout page?

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce, currency, checkout

I am working in word press woocommerce project. in which i am using plugin for multiple currency.I can change the current by adding currency type in URL like 
?v=c86ee0d9d7ed&currency=CH for Switzerland

and it is working fine on shop page, add to cart page. It is showing currency according country, but when i am clicking on checkout button. On checkout page the currency will not reflect, it is taking by default currency. it is euro.

I tried many time to change currency on checkout page according to country wise but did not get any solution. Can you help me, to solve my problem

thanks

Answer (score -3):

To change your shop currency settings go to: WooCommerce > Settings > General > Currency Options and select your desired currency from the Currency drop down.

[image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XPuxV.png)

If your currency is not listed go to  [custom currency](https://docs.woocommerce.com/document/add-a-custom-currency-symbol/)